# Xfce4 goes black randomly on DragonFly BSD release 4.2.4

Tags: bsd, xfce

The xfce4 desktop environment goes black on random occasions during use.

Install xf86-video-ffbdev.

Will post updates here, and the solution as soon as I've found it.

```
$ uname -v 
DragonFly v4.2.4-RELEASE #6: Sun Aug  9 13:25:14 EDT 2015     root@www.shiningsilence.com:/usr/obj/home/justin/release/4_2/sys/X86_64_GENERIC
```

> n00b207: you shouldn't need xf86-video-fbdev (that warning is because how Xorg probes available devices)

```
    $ pciconf -lv
hostb0@pci0:0:0:0:  class=0x060000 card=0x50001458 chip=0x0c008086 rev=0x06 hdr=0x00
    vendor     = 'Intel Corporation'
    device     = '4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller'
    class      = bridge
    subclass   = HOST-PCI
vgapci0@pci0:0:2:0: class=0x030000 card=0xd0001458 chip=0x041e8086 rev=0x06 hdr=0x00
    vendor     = 'Intel Corporation'
    device     = '4th Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller'
    class      = display
    subclass   = VGA


$ xset q
Keyboard Control:
  auto repeat:  on    key click percent:  0    LED mask:  00000000
  XKB indicators:
    00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    off    02: Scroll Lock: off
    03: Shift Lock:  off    04: Group 2:     off    05: Mouse Keys:  off
  auto repeat delay:  500    repeat rate:  20
  auto repeating keys:  00feffffdffffbbf
                        fedfffffffdfe5ef
                        ffffffffffffffff
                        ffffffffffffffff
  bell percent:  0    bell pitch:  400    bell duration:  100
Pointer Control:
  acceleration:  2/1    threshold:  4
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  600    cycle:  600
Colors:
  default colormap:  0x22    BlackPixel:  0x0    WhitePixel:  0xffffff
Font Path:
  /usr/local/share/fonts/misc/,/usr/local/share/fonts/TTF/,/usr/local/share/fonts/OTF/,/usr/local/share/fonts/Type1/,/usr/local/share/fonts/100dpi/,/usr/local/share/fonts/75dpi/,built-ins
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 600    Suspend: 600    Off: 600
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On
Font cache:
  Server does not have the FontCache Extension
```

> n00b207: could you try "xset dpms force off" to check if it freezes (might need to repeat few times to fully go into turn off screen mode)

dmesg output: http://pastebin.com/9tk5JCBf

> n00b207: looks like you hit xfce+Xorg combo, try "xset -dpms && xset s noblank && xset s off" to see if it repeats again

Comment: IMHO should be on http://superuser.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @g-v Ah, yes, can I migrate? Or just copy-paste?

Comment: AFAIK you can only flag the question as off-topic for moderators or just create new question and delete old one.